# when trying to write to a json file on my computer its saying the file isnt writable react native

Tags: json, react-native, expo-go

Error writing data to file: [Error: Calling the 'writeAsStringAsync' function has failed
→ Caused by: File '/data.json' is not writable]

```
const writeDataToFile = async (x,y) => {
  try {
    data[x] = y
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    const filePath = `./data.json`;

    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filePath, jsonData);

    console.log('Data successfully written to file:', filePath);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error writing data to file:', error);
  }
};
```

i tried asking AI but it said to use

```
const documentDirectory = FileSystem.documentDirectory || `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}expo-file-system/`;
const filePath = `${documentDirectory}data.json`;
```

but that is a temporary solution i want it to write to the file that is on my computer i am new to react native but i could find any solutions that i could understand

Comment: I think there are several reasons why it does not work. I have been using the same library and your `filePath` has to be the full path like so `file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/your actual file name.json` note that this path is for an Android device. Try this first and if it does not work, try changing the filetype to png or jpg instead of json.